# Why would my importxml not populateing all the columns when inside an IFS formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that works really well aka populates all the cells below with the data from the table located in the url. `=importxml("https://www.website.com/posts/qld-holidays","//tr")`

However, when I try and put this formula inside an IFS formula such as `=ifs(
    State="QLD",importxml("https://www.website.com/posts/qld-holidays","//tr"),
   State="VIC",importxml("https://www.tourismtribe.com/posts/vic-holidays","//tr"))` only the first value populates and the rest of the column is empty.

I don't know why but I need to be able to use a formula to make this work as my 'named range' (here State) can change.

Appreciate anny help as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

### `IFS` does not overflow into subsequent rows, this is why only the first row gets populated.

As a workaround you can use nested `IF` statements:

`=if(State="QLD",importxml("https://www.website.com/posts/qld-holidays","//tr"), if(State="VIC",importxml("https://www.tourismtribe.com/posts/vic-holidays","//tr")))`